# spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client not sending client_id to external SSO

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-oauth2, pingfederate, spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client

I'm using `spring-security-starter-oauth2-client` to try and configure a Spring Boot app to use my company's PingFederate SSO page, which is hosted on a different domain than the app. With my current configuration, an unauthorized user will be forwarded to the SSO page, but none of the necessary parameters (such as the client_id) are being passed in the URL, so it fails.

**application.yaml**

```
spring:
  mvc.servlet.path: /my-app/
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          pingfed:
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            client-id: foo
            client-secret: bar
            scope: openid, profile, email
        provider:
          pingfed:
            authorization-uri: https://sso.company.com/as/authorization.oauth2
            issuer-uri: https://sso.company.com
            token-uri: https://sso.company.com/as/token.oauth2
            user-info-uri: https://sso.company.com/idp/userinfo.openid
            jwk-set-uri: https://sso.company.com/pf/JWKS
```

**Oauth2Config.java**

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ClientConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

When I run the app and hit a protected page, it forwards me to the login page https://sso.company.com/as/authorization.oauth2 and I get a "client_id not found" type error.

When I hit this SSO from a working (non-Spring) application, the url includes the expected params:
https://sso.company.com/as/authorization.oauth2?client_id=foo&code_chanllenge=xyz&scope=openid&etc

What am I missing? Is there a way to change the login url without having to add all the params manually?

**UPDATE**
I managed to get it to work as expected by commenting out my "mvc.servlet.path". I believe this is an issue of Spring putting the default login at http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorization/pingfed, while my app runs at http://localhost:8080/my-app/, but I'm not sure how to configure around it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how I missed this, but the answer was to change the `authorizationEndpoint.baseUri` in the `SecurityFilterChain` configuration to include the mvc servlet path before the default login. (Spring will automatically add the "registrationId" to the end of the path.)

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ClientConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                    .authorizationEndpoint()
                        .baseUri("/my-app/oauth2/authorization")
        return http.build();
    }
}
```